# How to find the date of the last matching row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

So I have a master spreadsheet that has 20k+ rows containing monthly leasing data. It has information like a person's name, when they leased a car, what kind of car they have, etc. Most of the rows are the exact same except for the cell that states which month they leased it in (for ex., it will say 4/1/2016 or 5/1/2016).

I need to find the final row in the data that matches the other rows so that I can find out when they returned the car.

For example, if John Doe leased a honda pilot on 1/1/2016 and the last known report that shows that he still had it leased was 5/1/2016, I need to find the row that has "John Doe", "Honda Pilot", and "5/1/2016" on it. But, it won't show up on the report in the same sheet that lists the June leases or any of the following ones.

If someone could help me out with this, that'd be very appreciated since I'm really confused as to how to do this.

I'm using Excel 2010.

This is the formula I'm using now:

`=INDEX('Master Table'!A:A, MATCH('Master Table'!E45,'Master Table'!E:E,0))`.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that it only gets me the first date in which is appears in the sheet when I need the last one. I would attach a screenshot, but it contains confidential data that I can't put out onto the internet.

Feel free to ask any questions in case my explanation wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Give us a screenshot including row and column identifiers of your data... or some data to work with. It sounds like you want the max date based on two columns -- Lessee and Vehicle.

Comment: Sun, you are right! I'm gonna look up the max date formula (sorry I'm new to Excel and just haven't learned that one yet) and try to apply it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MAX() in Excel against a list of dates using multiple criteria](http://superuser.com/questions/626945/using-max-in-excel-against-a-list-of-dates-using-multiple-criteria)

Comment: I've tried using this formula, but it always gives me the very last date that's listed on the sheet at all, ignoring the criteria:
=MAX(IF(E:E =E2, if(H:H=H2,A:A)))

I tried using this one, but it always just gives me the date that appears in the Enrollment Date Column (I'm using the leasing ideas as an example, I work in Education):
=max(A:A * (E:E=E3) * (H:H=H3))

I'll try to attach a screenshot when I figure out how to. I need to fill in the "date dropped" column

Comment: you need to use the array formula MAX(IF()). see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746792/find-min-max-date-in-a-range-if-it-matches-criteria-of-other-columns

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving Edit mode.  If Done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I've attached the screenshot on Imgur http://imgur.com/Rm71VDi

Comment: Google Sheets will let you select the max date. I have an example from a [Vehicle Fleet Mgmt spreadsheet I made](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EV6TC6Fv085es-dxjqo1AEITGBXNzHlPHWak73AY0YI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think you have the wrong screen shot.  I don't see any information about leasing there, nor anything other than column headers.

Answer (score 0):

If your formula is giving the first entry of interest in an unsorted list but you need the newest entry then:

Sort the table by descending date (such that the most recent date appears first).

Your formula should then show the first matching element which will also be the newest matching element.

Comment: Well the master table is basically a compilation of reports which are all sorted by the date (earliest to newest), so changing the order to descending doesn't solve it

Comment: @MichaelO Currently you get the first matching element. Since you have the table sorted from oldest to newest, this matching element would also be the oldest matching element. Re-sorting the table such that it is newest to oldest would cause the matching element to still be the first matching element, but now the first matching element is also the newest matching element, meeting your criteria.